# MYSQL insert was successful but no data is added

Tags: mysql

here's the table structure

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.10.1

-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 01, 2012 at 12:20 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.63
-- PHP Version: 5.2.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `beta2_fetcher`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `rss_fetch_stack`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rss_fetch_stack` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourceData` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `sourceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fetched_ts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fetch_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sourceId` (`sourceId`,`fetch_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6866 ;
```

and heres the sql query i am trying to do :

```
insert into rss_fetch_stack set ts = '1343840864' , fetch_status='0', sourceId='42312' , sourceData='O:8:"stdClass":26:{s:2:"id";s:2:"12";s:7:"site_id";s:1:"3";s:5:"title";s:25:"عربي";s:3:"url";s:50:"someXML";s:7:"groupId";s:1:"0";s:8:"category";s:1:"6";s:7:"enabled";s:1:"1";s:13:"bypassCompare";s:1:"0";s:7:"isInner";s:1:"0";s:8:"useProxy";s:1:"0";s:8:"autoPush";s:1:"0";s:11:"autoPushAge";s:1:"0";s:13:"autoPushCount";s:1:"0";s:12:"byWordFilter";s:1:"0";s:15:"publishInterval";s:2:"10";s:12:"publishCount";s:1:"1";s:6:"preURL";s:0:"";s:7:"postURL";s:0:"";s:9:"deleteURL";s:0:"";s:8:"preTitle";s:0:"";s:9:"postTitle";s:0:"";s:11:"deleteTitle";s:0:"";s:12:"maxFetchNews";s:1:"0";s:13:"fetchInterval";s:1:"2";s:10:"wordFilter";s:0:"";s:11:"blockFilter";s:0:"";}'
```

i am trying to do it via phpmyadmin , it says one row added , and gives me the row ID ... but the table stays empty !!!

Comment: I don't see where you provided a value for fetched_ts, and that column is marked "not null".  Not sure how the insert could have been successful given that.  (The other thing you might try is committing after inserting, if that's necessary with phpmyadmin.)

Comment: Your insert is missing a NOT NULL column, `fetched_ts`, are you sure that the 1 row is not being mistaken for a row and is actually a MySQL warning?

Comment: @Marvo it worked , i changed the structure to NULL and it worked :) i never given attention for the NOT NULL , and never had any problems with it , this was the first time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set `fetched_ts` and defined it as `NOT NULL`.

Else you can run query like:

`insert into rss_fetch_stack values ( 'O:8:"stdClass":26:{s:2:"id";s:2:"12";s:7:"site_id";s:1:"3";s:5:"title";s:25:"عربي";s:3:"url";s:50:"someXML";s:7:"groupId";s:1:"0";s:8:"category";s:1:"6";s:7:"enabled";s:1:"1";s:13:"bypassCompare";s:1:"0";s:7:"isInner";s:1:"0";s:8:"useProxy";s:1:"0";s:8:"autoPush";s:1:"0";s:11:"autoPushAge";s:1:"0";s:13:"autoPushCount";s:1:"0";s:12:"byWordFilter";s:1:"0";s:15:"publishInterval";s:2:"10";s:12:"publishCount";s:1:"1";s:6:"preURL";s:0:"";s:7:"postURL";s:0:"";s:9:"deleteURL";s:0:"";s:8:"preTitle";s:0:"";s:9:"postTitle";s:0:"";s:11:"deleteTitle";s:0:"";s:12:"maxFetchNews";s:1:"0";s:13:"fetchInterval";s:1:"2";s:10:"wordFilter";s:0:"";s:11:"blockFilter";s:0:"";}',
'42312',  '1343840864' , '111111111', '0')` ;

//where 1111111 is `fetched_ts`

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax instead, it will definitely work:

INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES('data1', 'data2' )

Here's some examples:

- http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-data-into-table.html
- http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html